# Have to hit enter twice with fgets() in C?

Tags: c, input, buffer, newline, fgets

Good Morning, I'm having an issue with some C code where I am forced to hit enter twice each time input is entered if the length of the input is less than the size of 'guess'.

If the length of the input is longer than guess, I only hit enter once, and it functions normally.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, but I provided the function in question that I believe is the source of the problem along with the caller function and main just for context.

**Output:**

```
Guess a number: 5555555555
Invalid guess.
Guess a number: 55555555555
Invalid guess.
Guess a number: 555

Invalid guess.
Guess a number: 

Invalid guess.
Guess a number: 5555
```

When I remove the line:

```c
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); // Flush the input buffer
```

and I extend past the size of the buffer, I receive this output:

```c
Guess a number: 5555555555555555555555555555555555
Invalid guess.
Guess a number: Invalid guess.
Guess a number: Invalid guess.
Guess a number: Invalid guess.
Guess a number: Invalid guess.
```

**Function in Question**

```c
char * get_input(char * guess)
{
    print_message("guess"); // Prompt user to input a guess
    fgets(guess, sizeof (guess), stdin);
    if(feof(stdin))
    {
        printf("error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int ch = 0;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); // Flush the input buffer
    guess[strlen(guess)-1] = '\0'; // Erase new line character
    return guess;
}
```

**Caller Function**

```c
int make_guess(int *v_guess_count)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool valid = false;
    char guess[10] = {'\0'}; // Buffer to store the guess
    do
    {
        get_input(guess); // Get the input
        if(is_valid(guess)) // Check if the input is valid
        {
            valid = true;
            *v_guess_count += 1;
        }
    }
    while (! valid); // Keep asking for input until guess is valid
    result = assign_value(guess); // Assign the guess
    return result;
}
```

**Main**

```c
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int red = 0;
    int white = 0;
    int v_guess_count = 0;
    int target = get_target();
    bool game_won = false;
    while(game_won == false)
    {
        red, white = 0; // Reset to zero after each guess
        int guess = make_guess(&v_guess_count); // Make a guess. If it's valid, assign it.
        printf("guess is: %d\n", guess);
        compare(guess, target, &red, &white); // Check the guess with the target number.
        print_hints(&red, &white);
        if (red == 4)
        {
            game_won = true;
        }
    }
    printf("You win! It took you %d guesses.\n", v_guess_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets(guess, sizeof (guess), stdin);` is a problem, but not related to what you're asking about. `guess` is a pointer so `sizeof(guess)` is the size of the pointer itself, probably 8, not the length of the array that was passed. You should pass the length of the array as a parameter as well.

Comment: The reason you have to press enter again after the input is likely due to this: `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`  `fgets` already read the newline so you need another one to break the loop.

Comment: Get rid of the line `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`.  You do not need to "flush the input buffer".  Trying to flush the input buffer is a terrible, and terribly difficult, practice.  It's needed only when you're also using the `scanf` function — which your program, based on what you've posted, is not.

Comment: See also [How to properly flush stdin in fgets loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549).

Comment: See also [What does it mean to "flush the input buffer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337937)

Comment: If you find yourself kludging newlines, then you are perhaps mixing diffferent input functions (don't) or misunderstood how they handle whitespace. If you need to "waste" an input, then read the line with `fgets()` and simply forget it if it was incorrect. The `scanf` become tricky to handle if you have to validate and reject bad input.

Comment: The vast majority of the time when calling `fgets`, you want the size of the buffer to be reasonably huge, larger than the longest line you can imagine the user ever typing.  A popular size is 512.  You should not have to write code to handle the case where the buffer isn't big enough, and where `fgets` reads a partial line.  Your "buffer flushing" code *would* help to discard the unread remainder of the line in the case where the input buffer wasn't big enough — but, as you've seen, it causes grave problems in the case where the buffer *was* big enough.

Comment: `fgets` is not a perfect function.  One of its problems is that it's not easy to distinguish between the cases where it did or didn't have enough space, where it did or didn't read a whole like, and therefore whether there isn't or is a need for you to handle the extra, unread portion of the line.  My advice to you is to not worry, for now, about the case where it doesn't read a whole line — which is why i recommend giving it a huge buffer, that "can't overflow".

Comment: The absence of a newline is how you know if the buffer was too small (except possibly the last line in a file might not end with a newline). There are two scenarios: a) you needed a bigger buffer, b) the user was fooling around. For the first case, use a buffer that will always be big enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two somewhat-related problems.

**One.** In your function

```
char * get_input(char * guess)
```

your line

```
fgets(guess, sizeof (guess), stdin);
```

does not do what you think it does.  You want to tell `fgets` how big the buffer is, that is, how much memory is pointed to by `guess` for `fgets` to read into.  But in function `get_input`, parameter `guess` is a *pointer*, so `sizeof(guess)` is going to be the size of that pointer, *not* the size of the array it points to.  That is, you're going to get a size of probably 4 or 8, *not* the 10 that array `guess` up in `make_guess` is declared as.

To fix this, change your input function to

```
char * get_input(char * guess, int guess_size)
```

and change the call in `make_guess` to

```
get_input(guess, sizeof(guess));
```

For more on this point, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c/10349610#10349610).

**Two**.  Your array `guess` for reading the user's guess is too small.  Instead of making it size 10, make it size 500 or something.  That way it will "never" overflow.  Don't worry that you're wasting memory by doing that — memory is cheap.

The reason for making the input buffer huge is this: If you make the buffer small, you have to worry about the case that the user might type a too-long line and that `fgets` might not be able to read all of it.  If you make the buffer huge, on the other hand, you can declare that the problem "won't happen" and that you therefore don't have to worry about it.  And the reason you'd like to not worry about it it is that worrying about it is *hard*, and leads to problems like the one you've had here.

To use `fgets` strictly correctly, while worrying about the possibility that the user's input overflows the buffer, means detecting that it happened.  If `fgets` didn't read all the input, that means it's still sitting there on the input stream, waiting to confuse the rest of your program.  In that case, yes, you have to read or "flush" or discard it.  That's what your line

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

tries to do — *but* the point is that you need to do that *only if `fgets` had the not-big-enough problem*.  If `fgets` didn't have the problem — if the buffer *was* big enough — you don't want to do the flush-the-input thing, because it'll gobble up the user's next line of intended input instead, as you've discovered.

Now, with this said, I have to caution you.  In general, a strategy of "make your arrays huge, so you don't have to worry about the possibility that they're not big enough" is **not** a good strategy.  In the general case, that strategy leads to insecure programs and horrible security problems due to [*buffer overruns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

In this case, though, the problem isn't too bad.  `fgets` is going to do its best not to write more into the destination array than the destination array can hold.  (`fgets` will do a perfect job of this — a perfect job of avoiding buffer overflow — *if* you pass the size correctly, that is, if you fix problem one.)  If the buffer isn't big enough, the worst problem that will happen is that the too-long part of the input line will stay on the input stream and get read buy a later input function, thus confusing things.

So you do always want to think about the exceptional cases, and think about what your program is going to do under *all* circumstances, not just the "good" ones.  And for "real" programs, you do have to strive to make the behavior correct for *all* cases.  For a beginning program like this one, though, I think most people would agree that it's fine to just use a huge buffer, and be done with it.

If you want to go for the extra credit, and perfectly handle the case where the user typed more than the `fgets` input buffer will hold, you're going to first have to detect that case.  The code would look something like:

```
if(fgets(guess, guess_size, stdin) == NULL)
{
    printf("error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(guess[strlen(guess)-1] != '\n')
{
    /* buffer wasn't big enough */
    int ch = 0;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF); // Flush the input buffer
    /* now print an error message or something, */
    /* and ask the user to try again with shorter input */
}
```

But the point is that you do the `while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)` thing only in the case where `fgets` failed to read the whole line, *not* in the case where it succeeded.

---

If you're still with me, here are two somewhat-important footnotes.

1. I suggested changing your `get_input` function to take a second parameter `int guess_size`, but it turns out a better type to use for the sizes of things is `size_t`, so a better declaration would be `size_t guess_size`.
2. I suggested the test `if(guess[strlen(guess)-1] != '\n')` to detect that `fgets` wasn't able to read a full line, but that could fail (pretty badly) in the obscure case where `fgets` somehow returned an empty line.  In that case `strlen(guess)` would be 0, and we'd end up accessing `guess[-1]` to see if it was the newline character, which is undefined and wrong.  In practice it's probably impossible for `fgets` to return an empty string (at least, as long as you give it a buffer bigger than 1 to read into), but it's probably easier to write the code in a safer way than to convince yourself that it can't happen.  There are a bunch of questions elsewhere on SO about practically and efficiently detecting the case that `fgets` didn't read a full line successfully, but just now I can't find any of them.