# c scanf only integers and check if they are not s

Tags: c, scanf

I want to use scanf to get two integers separated by a comma from the user.
So the scanf is in a loop that checks if the user really gave two integers or just some random strings, and if he did gave strings the program prints an error message and loop again. (if the user gave two integers the loop breaks)

so this is my code:

```
unsigned int x, y;
printf("Please enter your coordinates: ");
while (true){
    fflush(stdin);
    if (scanf("%d, %d", &x, &y) == 2){
        printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);
        break;
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid format! please try again: "); // error message
    }
}
```

But when I run this the program just prints the error message endlessly.
From what I understand the program should wait again for another user input in the scanf (which is also why I did fflush, so it will clean the stdin buffer)

I really don't know what's going on, so any answer will help!
Thank you

Edit: I know that there are better ways to do it that scanf, but unfortunately I have to do it this way

Comment: `scanf` is no good for this sort of thing.  It leaves the unrecognizable characters on the input stream, where they cause endless trouble.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is a popular way to *try* to solve this problem, but it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219549).  Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215).

Comment: @SteveSummit and it is UB --`— The stream for the fflush function points to an input stream or to an update stream
in which the most recent operation was input (7.19.5.2).`

Comment: @SteveSummit add to the dupe links

Comment: @SteveSummit: Though it's perfectly reasonable to follow it up by just consuming from `stdin` until you hit a newline to discard the assumed garbage line and reprompting for a new line.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I disagree that's "perfectly reasonable".  `scanf`'s sole virtue is simplicity.  If, after every time you call it and it fails, you have to consume from `stdin` until you hit a newline to discard the garbage, that's not simple, and (IMO) it's not reasonable.

Comment: I never saw an example reading more than one value with scanf. Here is an [example link telling about troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/why-does-scanf-ask-twice-for-input-when-theres-a-newline-at-the-end-of-the-form).I would read one after the other, and "printf" what should be entered first. That would make it work in a simple manner, ask for e. g. x coordinate, `scanf("%d", &x)`, ask for y coordinate, `scanf("%d", &y)`, ... - or read a string with `scanf("%s", x_and_y_as_comma_separated_text)` and parse it yourself, split at comma, validate, handle syntax errors etc....

Comment: As usual, I suggest _less guessing and more reading_ (such as [these FAQs](https://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html) (**all of them; do it now**) and K&R2e (do the exercises as you stumble across them).